# Password function and arrays

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple password program, but the else if statement always applies, even if the password is put in correctly. This works fine if I use a single char instead of an array, and change "hotdog" to 'h', and I think it might have something to do with unseen characters, like a space or return. I was sure `cin.ignore()` took care of return/enter.
Sorry, I'm fairly new to programming.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "What is the password?\n" << std::endl;
    char password[20] = "NULL";
    std::cin >> password;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cout << password << " is your entry?\n";
    if (password == "hotdog")
    {
        std::cout << "Correct!";
    }
    else if (password != "hotdog")
    {
        std::cout << "Incorrect!";
    }
    else
    {
    }        
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: You are comparing pointers to strings instead of the strings. Use `strcmp()`. If that wasn't for **passwords**, `std::string` might be even better.

Comment: You probably want to use `std::string` instead of an array of char. This will let `==` do a sensible comparison (right now it's just comparing pointers, so it'll always be false because the string literal can't be at the same address as the array). Oh, and no *don't* use `strcmp` if you can avoid it (and you can).

Comment: 1. Use `std::strcmp` to compare C-style strings.  2. Better, use `std::string` instead of C-style strings.

Comment: Are you sure? That is for a **password**, not normal text.

Comment: @Deduplicator: What difference do you think that makes? No, he probably shouldn't be comparing to a literal at all, but if he's going to do that, using `std::string` is still better than using `strcmp`.

Comment: He should not use `std::string` but stay closer to the metal for passwords, so he can be sure to erase all (partial) passwords from memory when he is done with it.

Comment: @Deduplicator This is a toy program for learning purpose only. I'm sure any real password program won't be coded like this.

Comment: [Click Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) for details on using strcmp()

Comment: @YuHao: It is for learning => He should not learn doing things the wrong way.

Comment: @Deduplicator It's only used to learn how to use basic input/output/string comparison, in my opinion. There's **much much more** work to do if you consider the password issue.

Comment: @Deduplicator: If all code had to be written the "right" way, then nobody could ever learn anything useful. The problem here is clearly "how do I compare strings in C++", rather than "what are the best practices for writing a program that accepts and verifies passwords".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, change `char password[20]` to `string password`. This prevents a buffer overflow if they type in more than 20, and it enables you to use `==` for string comparison.

The code `std::cin.ignore()` ignores a *single character*.  You want to actually ignore the entire remainder of the line.   There is no way to ignore "everything else typed so far" because there may have been characters typed which are still buffered. In practice, it works well to treat input as a series of lines.

The most accurate way to ignore the rest of the line is to ignore all characters up to and including `'\n'`, which appears in the input stream at the end of the line (by definition).

```
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

which may require `#include <limits>`. Another way is to read a string and discard it:

```
std::string t;
std::getline( std::cin, t );
```

---

NB. Check your understand of `if...else` . Once you have `if ( condition )`, then the next `else` will already get everything that was not in that condition. It's pointless to actually write `else if ( !condition )`; and your final `else {` block can never be entered, because the previous two conditions were exhaustive.

Comment: Taught me alot, thank's Matt! And yes, I do understand if && else, but I guess I inserted it after 30 minutes of pondering just to see if it was eluding me somehow. Thank's again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you are using the `if-else` statement. Try this code out:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout << "What is the password?\n" << std::endl;
char password[20] = "NULL";
std::cin >> password;
std::cin.ignore();
std::cout << password << " is your entry?\n";
if (stricmp("hotdog", password) == 0)
{
    std::cout << "Correct!";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Incorrect!";
}
std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: FYI, I tested this and it does give the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

When I take your code and compile it, even the term hotdog does not work properly, I obtain the following:

```
What is the password?

hotdog
hotdog is your entry?
Incorrect!
```

As suggested above, a string is a better method and works as intended based on your requirements. Here is sample replacement code that works as intended (with this code spaces are allowed, with the other answers, spaces are not, it all depends what is intended):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    cout << "What is the password?\n" << endl;
    string password = "NULL";
    getline(cin, password);
    cout << password.c_str() << " is your entry?\n";
    if (password == "hotdog")
    {
        cout << "Correct!";
    }
    else if (password != "hotdog")
    {
        cout << "Incorrect!";
    }
    else
    {
        // Added from original; however, this should never occur
        cout << "Else?";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output of Replacement Code

```
What is the password?

hotdog
hotdog is your entry?
Correct!
```

Answer (score -1):

You had to use strcmp() function to compare strings properly in c++,so I added the cstring library:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string password;
    cin >> password;
    cout << password << " is your entry?\n";
    char hd [7] = "hotdog";
    if (strcmp(password.c_str(),hd) == 0){
        cout << "Correct!\n";
     }  
    else if (strcmp(password.c_str(),hd) != 0){
        cout << "Incorrect!\n";
     }
    else{
        cin.get();
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use `strcmp()` to compare strings in C++. Mixing C and C++ string functions like this is poor coding style.